# Autocomplete not working for enum -Swift 3

Tags: enums, autocomplete, swift3

i have made an enum as the following :

```
class Manager {

   enum Language {
        case englishLanguage

        static func english() -> Language {
            return englishLanguage
        }

    }
    static let sharedInstance = Manager()
    var language : Language?

    private init(){


    }

}
```

And for sure call the enum this way :

```
Manager.sharedInstance.language = .english() // or .englishLanguage
```

Now the issue is here when i write the  `= .` it doesn't complete `english` but it works with native code when writing `= .` it completes and says center,left,right..etc :

```
Label.textAlignment = .left
```

How is it possible to use my enum the same way as native and to see the values. i have made a big research there is no such a resource on the internet. Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your enum variable `language` is optional, so it wont  autocomplete.Generally autocomplete works with . prefix if the variable has already been initialized with an `enum` value.

So to get autocomplete results use ! operator

```
 Manager.sharedInstance.language! = .englishLanguage
```

Or assign the variable

```
class Manager {
    enum Language {
        case englishLanguage
        case nepaliLanguage

        static func english() -> Language {
            return englishLanguage
        }

    }

    static let sharedInstance = Manager()
    var language : Language = .nepaliLanguage

    private init(){


    }

}
```

This way your autocomplete works well.

```
 Manager.sharedInstance.language = .englishLanguage
```